# How can I use rvm within a Makefile?

Tags: ruby, rvm, nvm

Working on this project: https://github.com/cucumber/bool

There's a makefile to construct the various items, and I'd like to use RVM to be able to switch between rubies for the stuff within the ruby directory, however, when I give the makefile commands to switch rubies, I get a nasty error

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

Of course, it works just fine if I issue `rvm use 1.9.3` on the command line, so this is a symptom of something else, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: The question & answer is appropriate for nvm, too.   Can you add the nvm tag so that nvm people can find the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call RVM from cron (or a Makefile, I would expect) it's important to set up the right environment. The Scout team have a great blog article explaining this:

http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2010/09/07/rvm-and-cron-in-production

The important part is ensuring you have a full login shell so you have access to RVM.

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'the_command_inside_makefile"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good use for [an RVM wrapper script](http://deepakprasanna.blogspot.com/2011/06/rvm-wrappers.html), which will let you generate a shell script which loads a given RVM ruby instance into that environment without using the normal, interactive RVM setup.

For example:

```
rvm wrapper 1.9.3@bool ruby bool
```

... will create a wrapped script called 'bool' with a given Ruby selected.